# How to display the featured image for each post?

Tags: wp-query, loop, post-thumbnails

I have used the following code to display the featured image for each post, but nothing is showing:

```
     <div class="thumbnail-img">

<?php 




        $lastBlog = new WP_Query('type=post&posts_per_page=2&offset=1');

        if ($lastBlog->has_post_thumbnail()) {

            while($lastBlog->has_post_thumbnail()) {
                $lastBlog->the_post_thumbnail();
            } ?>

            <?php get_template_part('content-image', get_the_post_thumbnail()); 

        }




?>

</div>
<br>

<?php



        if( $lastBlog->have_posts()):

        while($lastBlog->have_posts()): $lastBlog->the_post(); ?> 



            <?php get_template_part('content-title', get_post_format()); ?>




        <?php endwhile;

    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</div>
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="thumbnail-img">
<?php 
    $lastBlog = new WP_Query('post_type=post&posts_per_page=2');
    if ($lastBlog->have_posts()) {
        while($lastBlog->have_posts()) {
             $lastBlog->the_post();
              if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                  the_post_thumbnail();
             }
         }
     }
  ?>
 </div>
```

-> Try Like This

Answer (score 1):

I use this way:

```
$args = array ( 'post_type' => 'slider');
$slides = get_posts( $args );

foreach($slides as $row){ 
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($row->ID),"full");
    echo $image[0];
}
```

Comment: I'm not using an image slider. All I wanted it to be able to display the thumbnail over the post title. I have edited the question to show exactly what I wanted.